# Please allow on-topic questions

Tags: feature-request, questions, scope

Eliminate rules regarding question types.  Asking for advice or opinion is sometimes the most valuable information one can receive - especially if a person is about to go down a long path that ultimately could be a Dead End.

I am wrestling with a sea change in some research I'm doing and it is impossible for me to choose a path because I am not experienced in many of them.

Only by asking experienced people, can I choose a path meaningfully.

However these kinds of questions are not allowed(!)

You risk becoming the "about.com" of the scientific community - a dubious honor at best.

Comment: Closely related: [How to ask a broad question on SO?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144460) Similar: [Why are useful questions on Stack Overflow being closed as non-constructive?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110350) See also: [Where can I ask a "how to get started" question on a Stack Exchange site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121705) and [Where to ask initial architecture library questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157319)

Comment: Have you ever thought that we might have made some questions off-topic *for a reason*? We don't just do things here for the sake of it.

Comment: You can usually ask away in the Chat Rooms but Main sites are for focussed Q&A.

Comment: see also: [Why is it so easy to block questions on Stackoverflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211596/why-is-it-so-easy-to-block-questions-on-stackoverflow)

Comment: Would you prefer to be the Yahoo! Answers of the scientific community?

Answer (score 7):

If we allow just every question without quality control, the site is doomed. There is actually a reason some questions are off-topic. They deem not to contribute to the overall knowledge base we are trying to build here.

Discussions on whether some subject is on-topic or not is best done on the site's own meta. Be aware that any subjective question is generally not allowed here.

Chat might be more open on subjective questions, but that depends on the rules in each room.

Comment: I didn't say allow off-topic.  If the question is on-topic, allow it.  Currently, that is not your policy.  Subjective questions add to the knowledge base.  Rooms with different rules invites chaos.

Comment: Censorship in the Scientific Community is, well, the last word.

NOTE:  I have to laugh, if I press ENTER to start a new paragraph, it sends the comment.  SO looks like it is basically a Smart Phone App.  I guess its back to the Scientific NewsGroups.